# how to delete everything except specific characters from a file in bash?

Tags: bash, tr

I have a file with a string in it:

```
aa12bb34cc z23abZY
123 87aab
6667771
```

so I want the output to be:

```
aabbcc ab aab
```

using tr I achieved this string as output:

```
aa bb cc ab aab
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest with GNU tr:

```
tr -cd 'abc ' < file
```

Output:

```
aabbcc ab aab
```

---

> `-d`: delete all `a`, `b`, `c` and white spaces
>
> `-c` use the complement. Delete everything but `a`, `b`, `c` and white spaces.

Comment: thank you, it works! can you please explain what tr -cd does?